# ASP.NET GridView with Font-Awesome icons

Tags: asp.net, gridview, font-awesome

I am trying to add a *Delete* function to the records in my ASP.NET GridView control.

I want to have a font-awesome trash icon which will execute the Delete function on click but I am having trouble getting it to display.

Here is my `template field`:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <!--Text="Delete" 
                    <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa"  onclick="Delete" runat="server">&#xf014;</i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o">
                    -->
                <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">                        
                    <button ID="lnkDelete" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ItemStyle-CssClass="fa fa-trash-0"
                            fontsize="24px" 
                            CommandName="Delete"/>
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

but after I deploy my Solution and refresh, I get this:

[image]

and I want something like this (but with just the *Trash icon*)
[image]

so what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Here's the answer that fits the buttons inside an `asp:GridView` control:  

    `<asp:GridView ID= ... >
       <Columns>
          ...
          <asp:ButtonField CommandName="myComand" ext="<i class='fa fa-info'></i>" 
          ButtonType="Link" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
          ...
       </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>`